# Combobox autocomplete .net

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

vi este codigo y quiero implementarla, en un datagridview, pero el problema es que este solo permite escribir un caracter, pero funciona. en autocomplete, como podria que este permita escribir completamente la palabra.

```
  private void comboBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            string name = string.Format("{0}{1}", comboBox1.Text, e.KeyChar.ToString());
            DataRow[] rows = dataTable.Select(string.Format("place LIKE '%{0}%'", name));
            DataTable filteredTable = dataTable.Clone();
           foreach(DataRow r in rows)
               filteredTable.ImportRow(r);
           comboBox1.DataSource = null;
           comboBox1.DataSource = filteredTable.DefaultView;
           comboBox1.DisplayMember = "place";

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si es winforms, con un textbox con keypress debería funcionar bien esa función.

```
    private void texbox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        string name = texbox1.Text;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)){ 
           datagridview1.DataSource = null;
           datagridview1.databind();
        }
        DataRow[] rows = dataTable.Select(string.Format("place LIKE '%{0}%'", name));

       datagridview1.DataSource = rows;
       datagridview1.DataBind();

    }
```

si es Web debes hacer una función asíncrona con javascript que vaya recuperando la información.